# Proximity Marketing API

Tags: android, eddystone

Currently I'm using AWS-S3 to create URL's for documents & shorten the URL's to suit the Eddystone format.

I'm using Kontakt beacons & use their UI to edit the beacons with shortened
URL's. This works fine, but the displayed link (as seen using the Physical
Web App) is too long & there is no link description.

I'm hoping to do all the above & more by using the Proximity Marketing API,
but the trouble is I'm an API Newbie & looking for some guidance.
I've created a Project & Browser Key & have a beacon, but not sure what to
do next (sorry).

I'm guessing I'll have to input the beacon details
somewhere together with the required URL & hopefully a link description.

Is there an idiots guide to doing this or what can you advise?

Answer (score 0):

The way the Physical Web App and Chrome's Physical Web support work is:

1. The app discovers Eddystone-URLs nearby.
2. The app sends the URL to a [Physical Web Service](https://github.com/google/physical-web/tree/master/web-service).
3. The Physical Web Service fetches the web page from that URL (following all the redirects, e.g., those introduced by the link shorteners).
4. The Physical Web Service extracts the title, description, icon, and [linked data](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/) from the web page.
5. The Physical Web Service returns the extracted data to the app.
6. The app uses the metadata to show the URL as it sees fit.

In other words, the only way to control how a Physical Web URL is displayed in Physical Web App or Chrome for iOS/Android is to manipulate the page's meta tags. But if you're linking directly to non-HTML files, then you naturally can't do that.

The best workaround I can think of would be to link to an HTML page with a **JavaScript redirect** (so that it's not followed by the service) to the actual document. You can then manipulate the content of the HTML page so that it's shown by Physical-Web–enabled apps as you'd like it to be shown. And when the user taps on the link, it'll open the page, which will then redirect the user to the document, initiating the download.

Comment: Thank you heypiotr your explanation was very helpful. I'll find out how to do that and let you know how I get on.